# Drupal 7 Mobile Page Load Issue

Tags: mobile, drupal, load

I'm working on a pre-existing Drupal (7.28) site.

[Daiya Foods](http://daiyafoods.com)

When viewing the site on mobile, the page loads on the left side of the screen, taking up about 25% of the space. Then, it snaps up to full size landing the user about half way down the page. The client would like it to be resolved (or explained) and I'm coming up empty.

[Screenshot of initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfmkS.png)

Thanks so much, and please feel free to contact me with any questions.

EDIT: This seems to happen on the homepage less often than interior pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely issue is your mobile meta tag in your `html.tpl.php` doesn't tell the browser what the initial zoom level should be. It's likely taking a few seconds for the browser to figure it out. Here's what you should have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Another possible issue is your CSS is rendering your `_desktop.scss` styles in mobile viewports. They should be wrapped in `min-width` media-queries. You have a lot of fixed widths in there that are likely making the layout flicker until the mobile CSS is parsed. You should be writing CSS in a mobile first approach in which all your mobile styles are not in media queries while your desktop styles are in `min-width` media queries.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give this a try. Thanks for your advice on the CSS as well.

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks again.